# Converting CSV to PHP Array - issue with end line (CR LF)

Tags: php, csv

I am converting csv file to an array using code bellow. But, problem is that end of the row is **CR LF**, and it is not detected, so array has wrong offset. CR LF is ignored and "cells" around it are merged.

How could i rewrite code to detect this row ending and split array correctly ? Or, is there better approach to convert csv to array?

There are some simmilar questions here but i have not found solution to this issue yet.

Thanks.

```
$fileName ='test.csv';   
$csvData = file_get_contents($fileName); 
$csvNumColumns = 11; 
$csvDelim = ";"; 
$data = array_chunk(str_getcsv($csvData, $csvDelim), $csvNumColumns); 

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `fgetcsv()`? full info on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Example usage from php.net

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid str_getcsv()  and work with fgetcsv() to avoid dealing with some of the end of line futz.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
if (($handle = fopen("fileName", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
      var_dump($data);  //array representation of one line of csv...
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

If you're on a Mac...

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.